# How do I move the panel in Visual Studio Code to the right side?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's at the bottom by default.

For example in the following image ,panel(Section D) is at the bottom, instead I want it to move to the rightside i.e., in the area where README.md editior shown in Editor Groups(Section C). [image]

Image Credits: (https://code.visualstudio.com/images/codebasics_hero.png)

Comment: The backcolor of scrollbar not is solid and the result is ... [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTmzS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTmzS.png)

Comment: You should update this question to accept the @dcastro 's answer.  The current accepted answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329503/836330 for creating another panel, like the Side Bar but on the opposite side of your current Side Bar - and separate from the Panel.

Comment: As of [v1.64](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_new-side-panel), the (bottom) Panel and the Side Panel stay where they are and you move "views" (debug, problems, output, terminal, search) between them.

Comment: @Denis: I just spent a half hour trying to get the terminal to show up on the left-hand side, instead of at the bottom (which seems to be the new default) or on the right.  I finally accomplished this, but I'm not sure how I got there.  And remote work seems to require that you keep an "install" thingy running, in addition to the terminal itself.  This new system is IMNSHO a disaster (not your fault, obviously!).  Anyway, can you say a little more about how you re-position the terminal?  I think you could rightly make it an "Answer", not just a comment.

Comment: View header > right-click > Move Views to Side Panel

Answer (score 957, accepted):

As of October 2018 (version 1.29) the button in @mvvijesh's answer no longer exists.

You now have 2 options.
Right click the panel's toolbar (nowhere else on the panel will work) and choose "move panel right/bottom":

[image]

Or choose "**View: Toggle Panel Position**" from the command palette.

Source: VSCode update notes: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_panel-position-button-to-context-menu

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the right click must be performed on the toolbar of the panel. (Clicking anywhere else won't help.)

Comment: How annoying. Constant changes.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts. Why did they take the button away in 1.29.1? It was consistent with Chrome's dev tools before and now it's not.

Comment: @colefner To remind you that you are using a Microsoft product: it ain't broke, but they sure as heck will go ahead and fix it.

Comment: This is the most up to date answer!

Comment: can we assign shortcut key to toggle panel position?

Comment: @shashwat Yes, open Keyboard Shortcuts and search for `workbench.action.togglePanelPosition`. You can add a keyboard shortcut that'll toggle it back and forth.

Comment: Thank you! This button to move right doesn't exit for me although I'm updated! (Mac)

Comment: Sometimes you need people to point the obvious; Thank you dcastro!

Comment: As of June 2019, the correct way of doing this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/56413015/1234260

Comment: The "View: Toggle Pannel Position" command appears to be gone in version 1.42.0

Comment: Using 1.44.2 (April 2020), and the command now requires you to specify the location: `View: Move Panel To Bottom`, `View: Move Panel To Right`, or `View: Move Panel To Left`

Comment: how to set the width pf right panel? anyone who know about it?

Comment: Can I just move one tool, say "Extensions" to the right, keeping everything else on the left?

Comment: Wait a second, hey everyone. This moves project files to the right as well! The question is - how to move only DEBUG ly window to the right, while keeping files to the left?

Answer (score 167):

For people looking for an answer (on how to move the side panel):

You can press

`ctrl` + `,` (Or `cmd` + `,` on OSX)

and add the following option to your user settings JSON file:

`"workbench.sideBar.location": "right"`

[image: SideBar on the left]

Comment: OP refers to the bottom panel, not the left sidebar.

Comment: @steph643 OP was not clear in his subject line which panel he was referring too.   Though his question clarified that nicely, it is the subject line that we see on Google search results.  This answer was the answer to the question that I had.  Too often it is forgotten that for the masses looking for answers, it is Google leading us around by the nose until we find somewhere that the right answer hasn't been denied us by some heavy handed and short sighted mod because it didn't  properly stand at attention and salute their astuteness.

Comment: @forres, is it possible to make panels floating and move them on to a separate monitor?  This is my usual setup when working with VS - code on left, all the panels on the right. Changing the anchor (left / right) of the sidebar does not change how much text editor is visible

Comment: I agree with @hawkeyegold - while the answer clearly _does not_ answer the OPs _intent_, it was incredibly helpful since I also googled this question while having the exact same question as Forres - wanting to move the workbench side bar. Many thanks!

Comment: downvoted because this answer is confusing and clogs up seeking correct answer. Author asked how to move `Panel`, not side panel. [Correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752348/2674033) belongs Stefano:
`"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"`

Answer (score 113):

I'm using Visual Studio Code v1.24.0 on a Mac.

By default, the Panel will appear on the bottom (You can change the default as well. Please refer to @Forres' answer: [Moving Panel in Visual Studio Code to right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874426/moving-panel-in-visual-studio-code-to-right-side/44468306#44468306))

Here's the bottom/right toggle button for VS Code Panel:

[image]

Once I click on this button, the Panel moves to the right.

[image]

Moving it back is a little tricky though. As you can see, some of the buttons are hidden. This is because the width of the panel when it's aligned right is too small. We need to expand the column to see all the buttons.

This is how it'll look upon expansion:

[image]

Now, if you want to move the Panel back to the bottom, click on the toggle bottom/top button again.

Comment: this so confusing. the bottom is just hidden and there's another that looks just like it.  bad UX

Comment: thank you very much for hidden buttons :D It really saved my time much

Comment: [Forres' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874426/moving-panel-in-visual-studio-code-to-right-side/44468306#44468306) moves the `sidebar` not the `panel`. The right way of changing the default panel location is [Stefano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874426/moving-panel-in-visual-studio-code-to-right-side/51752348#51752348)

Comment: This is not intuitive... they should add a "More..." button to show all hidden buttons

Comment: You can also open then command palette and use `View: toggle panel position`

Comment: The icon doesn't seem to be there anymore for me. Neither when the panel is at the bottom, nor when it's at the right. Even when the panels have enough width. I need to right click on the panel header to make it move right or bottom. Which sucks.

Comment: @oyalhi, the correct answer with latest Visual Studio Code (Version 1.32.3) seems to be `View -> Appearance -> Toggle Panel Position", like what @protoEvangelion mentions.

Answer (score 64):

Click menu option `View > Appearance > Move Side Bar Right` or in settings.json:

`"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"`

Comment: OP is referring to the bottom panel, not the workbench panel. The workbench panel is what contains the file explorer, extensions, etc. Unfortunately they're both called `___ panel` so it's easy for confusion to happen.

Comment: I think that the one you are thinking of is actually `workbench.sideBar.location`. Unless I messed up when copying my comment is correct, anyway I then noticed now there is a new button to move it to the side and back to the bottom.

Comment: Best answer on here. It moved my terminal (bottom) panel to the right just like I needed. Exactly as the op requested. Thanks!

Comment: It requires to close the existing terminal first, and do `CTRL` + ` to show them on the right side

Answer (score 37):

Click menu option `View > Appearance > Move to Side Bar Right`. Once side bar moves to right, option "Move Side Bar Right" changes to "Move to Side Bar Left".

Comment: This no longer exists

Comment: This has moved to View > Appearance > Move Side Bar Right/Left

Answer (score 37):

In version 1.55.2.

Go to View --> Appearance --> Move Panel Right[image]

Comment: this works for me, short and nice!

Comment: Works for version 1.62 too.

Answer (score 15):

As of June 2019 this setting can be found through searching 'Panel' - if you want to change the default there is an option for it as shown in the screenshot:[image]

Comment: The settings in JSON is "workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

For Visual Studio Code v1.31.1, you can toggle the panel session via the **View** menu.

- Go to the *View* Menu.
- Via the *Appearance* option, click on `Toggle Panel Position`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Hope this will help someone.

-> open to keyboard shortcut

-> search for "workbench.action.togglePanelPosition"

-> assign your desired shortcut

I've assigned keybinding "cmd+`"

```
{
  "key": "cmd+`",
  "command": "workbench.action.togglePanelPosition"
}
```

now I can toggle the terminal by pressing "cmd + `"

Comment: hmm strange for me on osx, terminal loses focus after I do this

Comment: @DanielLizik, now VSCode has the option "View-->Appearance-->Move Panel ___".

Answer (score 9):

[VSCode 1.42](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d19930276fd02cd2edd5eb17a8b55eb096a5b159/release-notes/v1_42.md) (January 2020) introduces:

> ### Panel on the left/right
>
> The panel can now be moved to the left side of the editor with the setting:
>
> ```
> "workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "left"
> ```
>
> This removes the command `View: Toggle Panel Position` (`workbench.action.togglePanelPosition`) in favor of the following new commands:
>
> - `View: Move Panel Left` (`workbench.action.positionPanelLeft`)
> - `View: Move Panel Right` (`workbench.action.positionPanelRight`)
> - `View: Move Panel To Bottom` (`workbench.action.positionPanelBottom`)

Comment: For me, I had to restart the VSCode to see changes.

Comment: @Chuan OK. For me, I am waiting for VSCode May 2020 1.46: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d5787d62216069e0b66b77c9470bb2d093c60e59/release-notes/v1_46.md#workbench

Answer (score 7):

With v1.64.2 they have brought back the command `View: Move Panel Right (or Left)`.  You can put the Panel (which typically has the Terminal/Output/etc. in it) as a vertical column on the left or right side - next to the Side Bar or Side Panel if you wish.

---

They are working on a fix for the change wrought by v1.64, should be in Insiders v1.65 02/08/2022.

Just use the `View: Move Panel Right/Left/Bottom` command from the Command Palette.

---

[Outdated answer, see above.]

As of Stable v1.64 the setting `"Wokbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"` will no longer work.

> Replacing Panel Location
>
> As mentioned above, the new Side Panel provides similar functionality
> as moving the Panel to the left or right, yet improves on this by not
> forcing the move of the original panel. Along with view drag and drop
> between panels, the new Side Panel is replacing the option to move the
> bottom Panel.
>
> In light of that, we have deprecated the
> `workbench.panel.defaultLocation` setting as well as the Move Panel...
> commands in favor of similar commands Move Views From Panel To Side
> Panel (`workbench.action.movePanelToSidePanel`) and Move Views From
> Side Panel To Panel (`workbench.action.moveSidePanelToPanel`). The old
> commands will remap to the appropriate new command providing the
> similiar behavior. Though, we recommend updating your keybindings to
> the new commands.

[image: panel location]

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#replacing-panel-location

This is in favor of using the new `Side Panel`, which can be in addition to the previous `Side Bar` (where the Explorer, SCM views traditionally are) and the Panel (where Terminal, Output, etc. traditionally are).  So you can have **3** panel-types of views.  See more at the v1.64 Release Notes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#new-side-panel

Comment: I *always* want the terminal on the left, I certainly don't want to have to use a command to move it there every time.  Does the command "move panel left" make this permanent?  Or do I have to run this command every time I start up VSC?  (Mark, I know you're not responsible for this, I'm just frustrated at this new system, which seems terribly opaque, and the release notes .)

Answer (score 6):

You can do the same in insider's edition, There is an option on right top corner to switch to the panel to sidebar https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

terminal at the bottom side
[image: terminal in the bottom side]

terminal at the right side
[image: terminal in the right side]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: There is a button just next to the  cross "x" icon

Comment: @pulankit Thanks, it dissapeared because the pane wasn't wide enough and I could not find it with popouts or something.

Answer (score 6):

[image: screenshot of vscode with terminal on the right side]

This answer is for people that just want their **terminal** on the   right side (shown above), and don't care about the panel.

1. Show vscode's Command Palette with keyboard shortcut `command + shift + p` or `ctrl + shift + p`
2. Type in "terminal editor"
3. Choose option that says `Terminal: Create New Terminal in Editor Area to the Side`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know since which version it change but the 1.11.2 has an option in View tab which can change the left bar to the right and vice versa

Comment: OP refers to the bottom panel, not the left sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

`"Wokbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"`

Open settings using `CTRL+.`, search for `terminal` and you should see this setting at the top. From the drop down below the settings explanation, choose *right*. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As sample as this from the GUI. View->Appearance->Move Side Bar Right

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right",
```

Comment: This answer is already provided by [this 2 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752348/466862). Please only post a new answer if you add a new solution or a significantly better explanation; otherwise just upvote the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `view`, then `appearence`. Then select move panel bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Command Palette from the wheel icon on the bottom left --> search and enter "settings" menu --> search "panel" in the search bar --> Select Default location as "right" instead of the "bottom".
Reload VS Code, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `⌘J` toggles the (bottom) panel.  If all your views are on the side panel, make `⌘J` toggle the side panel by doing:

Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > "Command+J" > Right-click > Remove Keybinding

Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > View: Toggle Side Panel > Add Keybinding > `⌘J`

Answer (score 0):

The panel opens on the right by default.

Note that this setting needs to be in a new folder to take effect.

If VSCode has opened the folder before, the panel will still use the old location.

`"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right",`