# How to adjust the position of the internal terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I made a mistake, I put vs built-in terminal position, from the bottom of the screen, change to the right side of the screen, but it doesn't work out, even more, more trouble is that I can't change the terminal from the right side of the screen to the bottom of the screen, I can't found such button!!!

Who can help me?
I have tried to delete "~/. Vscode" and software, and then decompress again, but the problem has not been solved!

BTW, my laptop system is ubuntu16.04, and the vscode version is v1.24.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move the panel in Visual Studio Code to the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874426/how-do-i-move-the-panel-in-visual-studio-code-to-the-right-side). I mean, technically you're asking how to move from right to the bottom and the other from bottom to right or left, but they're both "How to move the terminal" (as in your title) and both have the same resolution.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you move the `Terminal` split bar to the left (this will widen the `Terminal` window), the icon for `Move to Bottom` will appear.

[image]

**Updated on 9-May-2022:**

The current VSCode version as now is `1.67.0`. The below steps are still valid in current version of UI.

**Updated on 18-Nov-2018:**

Version 1.29 was released in October 2018 (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29) and the UI has changed for configuring the terminal position.

**1. Version check**

[image]

**2. Move Terminal From Right To Bottom**

[image]

**3. Move Terminal From Bottom To Right**

[image]

Comment: I'm using version 1.29.0-insider and that button seems to be missing.  Anyone know how to get it back?  I can still right click and move it, but I really liked the shortcut button.

Comment: Yeah seems gone in `1.29.0`, shame, i used it all the time.

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer, as of **v1.29** and @jay-chung now has the correct answer

Comment: @kevin @Caleb I've updated the answer to include `v1.29`. The UI has changed for moving the position from right to bottom and back.

Answer (score 32):

If you use VSCode `v1.29+`, this action button was moved to the Terminal context menu:

[image: vscode editor window]

just right click the `Terminal` tab on top of panel window, and you will see **Move Panel Right** or **Move Panel to Bottom**.

for more information, you can see: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58575

Answer (score 11):

You can also use View / Appearance / Toggle Panel Position
[image: View Appearance Toggle Panel Position]

Answer (score 7):

**Right Click on terminal then click on move panel**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Right Click on terminal then click on `Panel Position`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the newer update 2021, They have removed the icon but there is a solution.

=> Right Click on "Terminal":

[image]

=> Choose "Move Panel Bottom"

=> Done!

Answer (score 0):

2023 solution. This is on Windows 11

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## June 8, 2023

To be able to accomplish this you have to look into this image
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Press Ctrl + ` to go to the terminal and press Ctrl + 1 to go back to the editor.