# How do I place my terminal in the left side at visual studio code? Version 1.64.1 (2022)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to position my terminal at the left side of my visual studio code (as presented on the first image) but now the option to do that is gone, i think some recently update removed it (which seems strange, why would they remove a feature?).

After some googling, i found this [How do I move the panel in Visual Studio Code to the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874426/how-do-i-move-the-panel-in-visual-studio-code-to-the-right-side)
But it doest help me, as my problem is different

Someone knows how i can achieve the same result nowadays?

[image]

**What i already tried:**

1. Tried to add this command at settings.json *"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "left"* but it says it has been deprecated
2. Right click at terminal header does not show the "Move to Left" option anymore, instead there's only a Move Views to side panel, which results in a right-side placement, not left
3. View > Appearence does not have the desired option anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**v1.64.2** is out 02/10/2022 and this can now be done in that release.

Use the command:

`View: Move Panel Left` from the Command Palette.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! after i used this command the options that were previously missing have reappeared